# How can HD skins be used as Minecraft avatar in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The 64x32 pixels of the default resolution skin look rather poor if one uses an HD texture pack, but that's the only resolution allowed to for upload to the profile on [minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net/). I can of course play in offline mode, which gives me the texture pack's default `char.png`, which I could replace with my favourite HD skin, but in SMP everyone would look the same (if the server doesn't require online at first, that is).

Is there any possibility (vanilla, client mod, Bukkit plug-in, etc.) to walk around with HD skins in an HD world?

Comment: Are you suggesting that nowadays, we should play 3D games with characters of resolution 64x32 ? It is true that the game is abou blocks, but the look of the main character would not destroy it when you preserve the models and just place more detailed skins. Almost every object in that game was retextured. Even to such dimensions that one black contains 512x512. So there is no question the textures of the main character should be the outmost importance to us!

Comment: agreed, now just convince notch of this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/319038-) that allows for HD skins, ear skins, and capes via a third-party site. They will even show up for other players using the same mod on a multiplayer server.

Answer (score 6):

The possibility does not exist yet, but then again, why would you wanna do that? The whole game is about squares and pixels. This would ruin the experience of Minecraft.

I also remember something about Notch saying he wouldn't want that, because then people would bring 18+ stuff into the game via their character skins.

Comment: +18 stuff? did you look at a creeper? :p no, but seriously, there should be an option to turn off individual skins (or blacklist/whitelist certain ones) anyway...

Comment: of course this eliminates the charm of pixelation, but _when_ I play with a HD texture pack it would be nice if it were a consistent experience. In my case, I got a great skin drawn by hand, which downscaled to 64x32 unfortunately looks too blurry and I'm not much of a pixel artist (or patient enough atm) to manually pixelate it...

Comment: I see, but still, it doesn't work (yet), maybe notch will change this later, but i'm not sure

Comment: I haven't found a mod as of yet which does what you want. If I find one and I think of this conversation, I'll let you know :p

Comment: The default skin resolution actually doesn't stand out at all when using a 32x32 HD texture pack. Maybe if you're using a 64 or 128 HD texture pack it will. Besides, even if you could have HD skins, *everyone else* would still have their custom low-res skins in SMP.

Comment: @Sir Ksilem - There are HD texture packs that still keep the feel of Minecraft, yaknow.  (I love the Minecraft Enhanced pack.)

Comment: did you find a mod?

Comment: [invalidated](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21478/how-can-hd-skins-be-used-as-minecraft-avatar-in-smp/30192#30192), sorry :)